# Facebook API : How to get follower list of login user in facebook

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to get all the followers whom the login user following in the Facebook and get their name and profile image.

I am looking this script in IOS and PHP Both kindly suggest me how can I use this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "followers" in the Graph API. There was the `subscribers` edge, but it was deprecated with v2.0 nearly 1.5 years ago:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#

> `/me/subscribers` and `/me/subscribedto` have been removed.